# Websocket Connection Handshake Timed out

Tags: java, scala, websocket, playframework-2.3

```
public static WebSocket<JsonNode> chat(final String chatname, final String username) {
    Logger.info("Received request for WebSocket");
    return new WebSocket<JsonNode>() {
        public void onReady(WebSocket.In<JsonNode> in, final WebSocket.Out<JsonNode> out){
            ......
            //My Code never reaches here
        }
}
```

I see the Log entry "Received request for Websocket" and then it never hits onReady.

Play Version 2.3.10 and Scala Version 2.11.6.

Javascript code which looks straight forward

```
var WS = window['MozWebSocket'] ? MozWebSocket : WebSocket
var chatSocket = new WS("@routes.Application.chat(chatname, username).webSocketURL(request)")
```

Could someone point me in the right direction? There were some version mismatch issues causing exceptions and JVM to exit earlier and I was able to clear all of them, but this one is not giving any clue.

Chrome console shows error "handshake timed out"

Edit :: Javascript after scala compile

```
$(function() {

$("#onChat").show()

var WS = window['MozWebSocket'] ? MozWebSocket : WebSocket
var chatSocket = new WS("ws://localhost:9000/room/chat?chatname=topic&amp;username=test")

var sendMessage = function() {
    chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify(
        {text: $("#talk").val()}
    ))
    $("#talk").val('')
}

var receiveEvent = function(event) {
    var data = JSON.parse(event.data)

    // Create the message element
    var el = $('<div class="message"><span></span><p></p></div>')
    $("span", el).text(data.user)
    $("p", el).text(data.message)
    $(el).addClass(data.kind)
    $('#messages').append(el)
}

var handleReturnKey = function(e) {
    if(e.charCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        waitForSocketConnection(chatSocket,sendMessage);
    }
}

$("#talk").keypress(handleReturnKey)

chatSocket.onmessage = waitForSocketConnection(chatSocket,receiveEvent);

// Make the function wait until the connection is made...
function waitForSocketConnection(socket, callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (socket.readyState === 1) {
            console.log("Connection is made")
            if(callback != null) {
                callback();
            }
            return;
        } else {
            console.log("wait for connection...")
            waitForSocketConnection(socket, callback);
        }

    }, 1000); // wait 5 milisecond for the connection...
}

})
```

Routes

```
GET     /                                controllers.Application.index()
GET     /room                          controllers.Application.chatRoom(chatname: String ?= null, username: String ?= null)
GET     /room/chat                       controllers.Application.chat(chatname, username)
GET     /assets/javascripts/chatroom.js  controllers.Application.chatRoomJs(chatname, username)

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file                    controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

Comment: I need more information, what's your final java script after scala template be compiled? 

Here some directions:
here we used  `@routes.Application.chat(chatname, username).webSocketURL()` without the request parameter, but it was for play 2.2.6.

Also, check for https/http and wss/ws compability.

Are you under apache or nginx? If yes, you need to config it up to accept WS protocol.

Hope it helps.. :)

Comment: try this to validate your backend: http://www.websocket.org/echo.html

Comment: @nipo - edited my question with final Javascript

Comment: I added [chat, superchat] protocols to the WS, but no help... [link](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455)  `Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Upgrade
Host:localhost:9000
Origin:http://localhost:9000
Pragma:no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key:Nf5L84QTL3GbFc452rIOCA==
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol:chat, superchat
Sec-WebSocket-Version:13
Upgrade:websocket
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87...`

Comment: Have you tried to connect using [websocket.org/echo](http://websocket.org/echo.html)? That is just to validate your backend, after that you can try follow the pattern in the answer I'm posting now.

Comment: I think its not an issue with JS - some server side issue.  Yes websocket.org/echo also failed to connect

Comment: @KrishnaA if websocket.org/echo failed to connect then it is most probably a backend problem. Can you show us the `routes` file and especially the entry with the websocket

Comment: @Anton, I edited my question - added routes.  GET /room/chat is the one which is mapped to the WebSocket<JsonNode> method in controller

Comment: @KrishnaA just for a test - try to define a route which does not accept parameters - like `GET /room/chat    controllers.Application.socket()`. You can pass the parameters later, in the `onopen` callback.

Comment: @Anton - I tried but still the same. "Still in connecting state" and after sometime "Handshake timed out"

Comment: @KrishnaA then I am pretty sure that your client-side implementation is wrong. Can you try with the JavaScript code that was posted by nipo. This should work

Comment: I did that...my guess is that its something wrong at server...When the request is going to the server and I see the log entry before return new WebSocket,  I don't think its client's issue.

Comment: Your routes is OK, but here we don't use paramenters: `GET   /tasks/widget                                                                     controllers.TaskController.widgetTask()`. I'm editing my answer to add more information for the controlers, I just realised you are using Play 2.3.x.

Comment: @KrishnaA - Do you have any news about your issue? Did my answer help?

Comment: @nipo - thanks for all help. The solution you provided may work but never tried as I was running out of time to build a prototype and hence moved to nodejs where i am more comfortable than play java. :)

Answer (score 0):

## Back-end

**Controller - Java 8**

```
import play.mvc.WebSocket;

public static WebSocket<String> socket() {
    return WebSocket.withActor(MyWebSocketActor::props);
}
```

**Controller - Java 7**

```
public static WebSocket<String> socket() {
    return WebSocket.withActor(new Function<ActorRef, Props>() {
        public Props apply(ActorRef out) throws Throwable {
            return MyWebSocketActor.props(out);
        }
    });
}
```

**Actor - Handler**

```
import akka.actor.*;

public class MyWebSocketActor extends UntypedActor {

    public static Props props(ActorRef out) {
        return Props.create(MyWebSocketActor.class, out);
    }

    private final ActorRef out;

    public MyWebSocketActor(ActorRef out) {
        this.out = out;
    }

    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        if (message instanceof String) {
            out.tell("I received your message: " + message, self());
        }
    }
}
```

**Source**: [link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaWebSockets)

---

## Front-end

**jQuery**: https://github.com/ffdead/jquery-graceful-websocket

**Javascript**:
That's the pattern we use here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>WebSocket Test</title>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  var wsUri = "ws://YOUR_URL"; // it should be wss:// for https connections
  var output;

  function init()
  {
    output = document.getElementById("output");
    testWebSocket();
  }

  function testWebSocket()
  {
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
    websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
    websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
    websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
    websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };
  }

  function onOpen(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen("CONNECTED");
    doSend("WebSocket rocks");
  }

  function onClose(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen("DISCONNECTED");
  }

  function onMessage(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: blue;">RESPONSE: ' + evt.data+'</span>');
    websocket.close();
  }

  function onError(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + evt.data);
  }

  function doSend(message)
  {
    writeToScreen("SENT: " + message);
    websocket.send(message);
  }

  function writeToScreen(message)
  {
    var pre = document.createElement("p");
    pre.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
    pre.innerHTML = message;
    output.appendChild(pre);
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", init, false);

  </script>

  <h2>WebSocket Test</h2>

  <div id="output"></div>
```